# RSA Cryptography javascript

Tags: javascript, rsa

I'm trying to build an user login/authentication client for a RESTful webservice created by me. 
However, while trying to setup authentication using the authentication API's available JAX-RS, I had some troubles and decided to change the approach. Now, what I'm actually trying to do is: 
The webpage sends an ajax POST request to an uri (user/login) contained with his email and his password separated by an ":" symbol. This message body will then be encrypted using the RSA algorithm in the client using some JavaScript lib and decrypted on the server side.

The problem is: I used Java to generate the PublicKey, and they are stored as an base64 string, encoded using X509 padding.

How can I decode this encoded string, which represents the Public Key, using only JavaScript, and actually use it to encrypt some text?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why encrypting on client? In JavaScript? Why not use SSL?

Comment: If you're encryption is client side, what's the point of encrypting it if I can MITM and decode it using your client side source? You're better off with SSL.

Comment: I'm encrypting it using a public key a decrypting it using a private key stored in the server also in a secure way. MITM attacks, as I first see, are though to happen since it's almost impossible to know the PrivateKey given a PublicKey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to encrypt just message body? Just make your AJAX request over **SSL** - your whole transmission will be encrypted.

This will require only minimal changes in your code (put `https` in front of url) and you don't have to worry about encryption in javascript.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't know how to handle it on the server. I'm using Jersey on Tomcat currently and I didn't find anything helpful regarding this.

Comment: There's no need to 'handle it on the server' in any special way - just enable SSL. I'm an IIS guy so can't help you with Tomcat settings.

Answer (score -3):

Once i've used a JQuery plugin in order to decode a base64 string.

```
$.base64.decode('yourstring');
```

More info here. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/base64

Comment: Encrypting and encoding are two different concepts.